# getSource() returns an empty table in CakePHP 4

Tags: php, cakephp, orm, traits, cakephp-4.x

I am currently updating a project from CakePHP 3 to CakePHP 4, and in this project I have a `Trait` that implements a "common" virtual property that some of the entities need.

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class NewsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('news');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');
        // more config here...
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;

class News extends Entity
{
    use SitemapTrait;

    protected $_virtual = ['sitemap'];  // this is the virtual property that the trait should take care of
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

trait SitemapTrait
{
    protected function _getSitemap()
    {
        $table = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get($this->getSource());
        // more logic here...
    }
}
```

The problem is that, on the `_getSitemap()` method, `$this->getSource()` returns a generic `Cake\ORM\Table` object, rather than a `App\Model\Table\NewsTable` object as I would expect, so everything that should happen afterward will not work.

I also wrote a simple command to check what happens when `getSource()` is called directly on an entity, and in this case I get the correct result, so the problem seems to be specifically related to it being called inside a `Trait`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Command;

use Cake\Command\Command;
use Cake\Console\ConsoleIo;
use Cake\Console\Arguments;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

class OrmTestCommand extends Command
{
    protected $newsTable;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->newsTable = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('News');
    }

    public function execute(Arguments $args, ConsoleIo $io)
    {
        $news = $this->newsTable->find('all')
            ->first();
        print_r($news->getSource());
    }
}
```

In this case I correctly get a `App\Model\Table\NewsTable` object.

I don't get why this broke going from CakePHP 3.5.18 to 4.3.11. Do I need some extra config in my model? What am I doing missing or doing wrong?

Comment: May not the solution, but https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/appendices/4-1-migration-guide.html#id3  `Cake\ORM\TableRegistry` is now deprecated. May use the new version and check is it fixes your issue. But switching from 3.5 to 4.1 is a huge jump. You should check all migration guides here https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/appendices/migration-guides.html

Comment: @Foobar I tried switching to Cake\ORM\Locator\LocatorAwareTrait::getTableLocator() and I get the same result. Also, of course I didn't directly go from 3.5 to 4.1. I followed all the upgrade guides step by step.

Comment: Wherever you're obtaining the entity, it's obtained from a table object that is a generic ORM table instance, meaning the concrete table class couldn't be found (spelling errors are the most common problem). This is where you need to start investigating, the code that obtains the table from which you get the entity.